# Alignment of absolutely positioned divs off by 1px at some zoom levels

Tags: html, css, layout, css-position

I have two absolutely positioned divs that I have lined up to look like an "L" or a kinked pipe. On Chrome at 100% zoom on a MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019), it looks like this:

[image]

The issue is that as I adjust the browser zoom level, the two divs go in and out of alignment by one pixel. For example, this is what it looks like at 90% zoom:

[image]

And the same thing happens at 110% zoom. If I adjust the position by `1px`, it goes back into alignment. What causes this, and is there a way to prevent it all zoom levels?

Here is a working example on codepen: https://codepen.io/elethan/pen/gOLQXrB

CSS:

```css
#outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
}

#progress-bar {
  background: purple;
  height: 40px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 4px solid gray
}

#down {
  background: purple;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 10px solid gray;
  border-top: 0 solid transparent;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 124px;
  top: 54px;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div id="outer-container">
  <div id="progress-bar"></div>
  <div id="down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I saw this problem when I enlarged the screen by 110%, and I can say that this shift is not equal to 1pixel. If you change rule top: `54px` to top: `55px`, you get a small gap between the elements - https://ibb.co/tPWv84P and https://ibb.co/Wp6wTSG.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov  , its not working, when you zoom at 100%.

Comment: In my opinion, it is better to use `svg` to implement such shapes. With svr such "phenomena" will not arise.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil, But that was not the solution. It was just analysis and testing.

Comment: I thought it was the solution, lol, the problem here is in the padding of the second div,  it takes the color gray, the second div should be at the bottom of the first div including the padding of the second div, for SVG solution, they are slower than CSS.

Comment: I can see the phenomenon on Chrome on WIndows10. I don't think it's out by 1 CSS pixel but by 1 (or a multiple thereof) screen pixels - a sort of rounding error when the system is trying to calculate where to stop showing things. It is capable of having half a CSS pixel for example if one CSS pixel maps to 2x2 screen pixels. Mixing % units with px units there is likely to be times when it doesn't get whole numbers. Some systems seem better at compensating for this than others - phenomenon not seen on my iPad e.g.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer

It happens due to the poor accuracy when dealing with floating point numbers in browsers.

The worst part is that they round differently the rendered element (what we actually see) from the element's size or positioning (the size they occupy or are placed at).

That's why some elements seems to be +/- 1 pixel from the position they should be. It can vary depending on the rendering engine and even the size of your window, as you can try, it seems to fix/break each pixel you resize.

### Example

In Firefox at 90% zoom:

[image: example]

- The `padding` of `outer-container` from `10px` renders **9** (it's fine).
- The `border` of `progress-bar` from `4px` renders **3** (rounds down from 3.6)
- The `content` of `progress-bar` from `40px` renders **36** (it's fine).
- At the moment: 9 + 3 + 36 = **48**.
- The `top` position of `down` from `54px`, renders at **49** (rounds up from 48.6).

In this case, the problem seems to be the rounding up for the `down`'s position `top`, and rounding down the `border`'s width of `progress-bar`. That's the empty pixel between `progress-bar` and `down` boxes.

That's just an example of a couple of elements in a single browser, as you can imagine, it will happen all the time with each element in the screen for each browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution, I changed the position of #outer-container to relative, because it to hard to use position absolute for all your divs.

```
#outer-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40pxpx;
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have the same issue with this solution. Here is a pen with your styles: https://codepen.io/elethan/pen/GRNeRWM Just like my other pen, it looks fine at 100% zoom, but is off at 90 and 110%.